# Typescript: How to summarize an interface

Tags: typescript

I want to merge following two interfaces.

```
interface LanguageSet {
    'type': 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE'
    'language': 'ko-KR' | 'en-US'
}

interface TitleSet {
    'type': 'CHANGE_TITLE'
    'title': string
}
```

Could you give me any help?
Thank you! :)

+)More Information
For example, when 'type' is CHANGE_LANGUAGE, you can't use title but can language. However, when 'type' is CHANGE_TITLE, you can't use language but can title.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? What would be the result of such a merge?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel It means that I want two interfaces to make one interface.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel For example, when 'type' is CHANGE_LANGUAGE, you can't use title but can language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using union types:

```js
interface LanguageSet {
    'type': 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE'
    'language': 'ko-KR' | 'en-US'
}

interface TitleSet {
    'type': 'CHANGE_TITLE'
    'title': string
}

type MergedInterface = LanguageSet | TitleSet;
```

This means that it can be either a LanguageSet or a TitleSet.

Comment: Thanks for your help! And I want you to ask one question.
Is there function that use conditional statement in interface?

Comment: @GMSIAME Runtime checking of types is not built in. You'll just have to do `switch (set.type) { case 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE': ... }`

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I realize something I didn't know.